# Not able to receive curl data at server side in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, php-curl

I am trying to dump data at server side with this code

```
        $ch = curl_init('http://test.com/usage_log');
        $data  = array('abc' => $abc);
        $post_data = $data;
        
        log_message('error',http_build_query($post_data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

and below is server side code that I am using to receive the data

```
      $abc          = $_REQUEST['abc'];
```

But I am getting below error at server side.

```
    <p>Severity: Notice</p>
    <p>Message:  Undefined index: abc</p>
    <p>Filename: controllers/Home.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 1529</p>
    <p>Backtrace:</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use curl

```
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
```

before curl close.

Comment: I am trying to make connecting to server with ssl. so at the end of day found that it was 302 error and ssl certificate